# Importing class in multiple files

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I couldn't find a solution on google about that...
So I'm programming in python a GUI where you have two windows: one main window and one temporary window which allows make some changes. The main window is located in main.py and the other in tmp.py.
from the temporary window I want a button which allows me to go back to the main window.. this means that from tmp.py I have to call the window in main.py. 
So in main.py I have:
import tmp

I don't think is correct in tmp.py putting:
import main
because it would redefine the same class... so what do you think should be the correct way of procedure... I hope I made myself clear enough is not that easy to describe... that's probably why I haven't been able to find a solution on google.

So essentially the code should be:
in main.py

```
import tkinter as tk
import tmp

class MainStr(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(StartPage)

    def switch_frame(self,frame_class):
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master)
        chbtn = tk.Button(self,text='Tmp page',command=lambda:master.switch_frame(tmp.page))
        chbtn.grid(column=0,row=0)


a = MainStr()
a.mainloop()
```

in tmp.py

```
import tkinter as tk
import main

class page(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master)
        chbtn = tk.Button(self,text='Home page',command=lambda:master.switch_frame(main.StartPage))
        chbtn.grid(column=0,row=0)
```

Many thanks

Comment: You can change the project structure so that everything is contained in `main.py`, among other things, but more advice than that would require to see how your code looks like and how it's structured

Comment: Sorry you're right... I tried to simplify the code I hope is clearer now... having everything in one file is too messy if you have large projects

Comment: OK thanks for posting the code, I now have an answer for you, posted below

Answer (score 2):

I would make a new file called `startpage.py` and put your StartPage class in it. Then you can import startpage.py from main.py and tmp.py. When you have done that, you can remove the `import main` statement from tmp.py.